# Data in a dataset are shifted irregularly in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shift

I am trying to simulate an experiment in a mathematical model. Resulting dataset contains data from the experiment - output data (out_exp) which are a result of input data (inp_exp) - and data from the simulation of the experiment- output data (out_sim) which are a result of input data (inp_sim).

When I merge all data to a dataframe, an irregular shift among simulated and experiment datasets can be found. In order to be able to compare and evaluate the out_exp and out_sim, both inp_exp and inp_sim has to start from the same date. It means I need to shift data from simulation (inp_sim and out_sim) together according to input data (ie. inp_exp[i] == inp_sim[i]). A problem is that the shift between input data is not regular (see data below).

Does any one have an idea how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Original data:

```
inp_exp <- c(0,0,5,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,4,8,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,5,8,9,9,1,0,0,0)
inp_sim <- c(0,0,0,5,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,8,1,2,0,1,5,8,9,9,1,0,0)

out_exp <- c(0,0,0,1,4,5,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,5,8,2,0,0,0)
out_sim <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,1,5,6,4,1,0)
D <- seq(as.Date("2018/10/2"), by = "day", length.out = length(inp_exp))

df <- data.frame(D, inp_exp, inp_sim, out_exp, out_sim)
df
```

Expected result:

```
inp_exp <- c(0,0,5,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,4,8,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,5,8,9,9,1,0,0,0)
inp_sim <- c(0,0,5,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,4,8,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,5,8,9,9,1,0,0,0)

out_exp <- c(0,0,0,1,4,5,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,5,8,2,0,0,0)
out_sim <- c(0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,6,4,1,0,0)
D <- seq(as.Date("2018/10/2"), by = "day", length.out = length(inp_exp))

df <- data.frame(D, inp_exp, inp_sim, out_exp, out_sim)
df
```

Comment: I would think you'd want to identify and resolve the issue that causes the shift instead of just trying to undo it.

Comment: I have already spent a lot of time doing so. Otherwise, I would have posted here. The issue might be somewhere in the calculations used in the software, but I am not able to find it where exactly it is. The shift is different in every event. What I am doing is that I am simulating rainfall which infiltrates into a infiltration trench. Water than flows trough the trench. In my case, the trench is represented by cylinder with the soil. The rainfall is simulated by a peristaltic pump. As the software is limited I had had to make some simplification and neglecting.

Comment: One idea might be to assign an ID to each observation and use the same IDs for your simulated observations, then merge them after. But I don't know enough about the process that leads to the shift to know if the IDs would carry through.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this idea. If you are interested in a solution, I could post it here afterwards